# Logrotate not doing his job, hdd full because of logs

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

I have a small microSD ( 3GB ) on a ARM Samsung Artik, with Ubuntu installed.

I have installed syslog-ng and Logrotate to manage my logs, because otherwise my memory get filled quickly.

My problem is with `/var/log/daemon.log.1` and `/var/log/syslog.1`, they are growing quickly and filling the disk, I must delete them manually when they are >500MB.

When I check my config, I have

```
systemctl status syslog-ng
● syslog-ng.service - System Logger Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-09-26 07:07:34 CEST; 1 day 1h ago
     Docs: man:syslog-ng(8)
  Process: 19072 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2079 (syslog-ng)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 30.7M
      CPU: 36min 58.590s
   CGroup: /system.slice/syslog-ng.service
           └─2079 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F
```

And logrotate:

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate/status 
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/syslog" 2019-9-27-6:25:3
"/var/log/dpkg.log" 2019-9-1-6:25:2
"/var/log/error" 2019-9-25-6:53:50
"/var/log/auth.log" 2019-7-7-6:25:2
"/var/log/apt/term.log" 2019-9-1-6:25:2
"/var/log/apt/history.log" 2019-9-1-6:25:2
"/var/log/alternatives.log" 2019-8-1-6:25:2
"/var/log/debug" 2019-9-13-6:43:24
"/var/log/kern.log" 2019-7-7-6:25:2
"/var/log/ufw.log" 2019-9-27-6:0:0
"/var/log/daemon.log" 2019-9-27-6:25:3
"/var/log/wtmp" 2019-9-1-6:25:2
"/var/log/mail.warn" 2019-9-27-6:0:0
"/var/log/btmp" 2019-9-1-6:25:2
"/var/log/mail.err" 2019-9-27-6:0:0
"/var/log/mail.info" 2019-9-27-6:0:0
"/var/log/cron.log" 2019-7-7-6:25:2
"/var/log/messages" 2019-9-27-6:25:3
```

Here it seems that daemon.log and syslog.log are being rotated.

here is /etc/logrotate.d/daemon

```
/var/log/daemon.log {
        monthly
        size 25M
        rotate 6
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
        notifempty
        create 644 root root
}
```

and /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        size 25M
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

But when I run manually

```
logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Files are not rotating.

When I do:

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf
```

files are actually rotated, but I don't know how to make it automatic...

Any why is this happening ?